# Identifying function parameters as Input or Output

Tags: c++, doxygen

So I have a simple function along with some documentation:

```cpp
/**
 *  @param[out] dest is overwritten by the second argument
 *  @param[in] src is value to overwrite the first argument with
 */
void Copy(int &dest, int src) { dest = src; }
```

Probably not very useful but it is quite clear that `dest` is output. However, the line gets blurred for me by the use of pointers:

```cpp
void Copy(int *dest, int src) { *dest = src; }
```

Should `dest` be still an output? The value of the pointer does not get modified, only the value in the memory where it points to does. But I'd still say probably yes. Moving on:

```cpp
void Write(FILE *fw, int src) { fwrite(&src, sizeof(src), 1, fw); }
```

Now that is really dubious for me and I would mark `fw` as an input, despite it is logically an output and also the contents of the `FILE` structure will get modified in the process (but that one is quite opaque to me).

On the other hand:

```cpp
void Open(FILE &*fw, const char *filename) { fw = fopen(filename, "w"); }
```

Is clearly output. The `FILE` handle is initialized by the function, the value of the pointer is overwritten.

Is there a good rule of thumb or reasoning for marking the arguments as output?

I don't even want to get into `[in,out]` arguments as with C++, those are basically all the `[out]` arguments (e.g. if passing output through a `std::vector`, the function needs to get an instance as an input and the output may even reuse the storage).

Answer (score 5):

[Opinions vary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Drawbacks) on whether output parameters should even be used, let alone how they should be documented. Still, they are in common use and your question is valid.

Whether a parameter should be marked as `[in]`, `[out]`, or `[in,out]` depends on the purpose of the parameter.

Usually, the purpose of an output parameter is to allow the called function to pass additional information to the calling function, when a single return value is inadequate. This "additional information" is passed via a reference parameter provided by the calling function. The reference parameter might be provided using the C++ reference operator (`&`), or by a pointer, which is a slightly different vehicle but which has the same result.

So *if the purpose of the parameter is to allow the called function to provide information to the calling function*, then it should be identified as an *output* in the documentation.

If a file handle or a filename is provided to a function through a parameter, that would be considered an *input* parameter, even though the function is intended to write to the file. This is because

- the function is not passing information back to the calling routine via the parameter
- writing to the file is considered a [side-effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) of the function.

If a reference parameter is used to pass information in both directions, then it should be documented as `[in,out]`.

**Furthermore**

When documenting a function, think of the function as a service that is being provided to the caller(s). The audience for your documentation is the programmer writing the code that will call your function. Write the documentation as though you, the writer of the function, are unaware of the context or specifics of the calling code. The purpose of the documentation is to describe in general what the function does, and in detail how to use the function.

So if the designer of the function intends that `dest` be used as an output, it should be marked as an output. You should also consider the case when the caller is not interested in the data provided via that output. Usually this is indicated by the caller providing a null pointer as the argument to that parameter. Before writing any data to `*dest`, your function should test to make sure `dest` is not null. The documentation for parameter `dest` should state that if `dest` is a null pointer, then no data will be written.

**Use const for Input Pointer Parameters**

As an aside, if a pointer parameter is intended for input only, that parameter should be modified with the `const` keyword, as follows:

```
void Copy(int *dest, const int *src) { *dest = *src; }
```

This has the following benefits:

- It will prevent the `Copy` function from writing to the `*src` location, if the programmer of the `Copy` function were to mistakenly attempt to do that
- It informs and reassures the programmer writing the code that calls `Copy` that his `src` buffer is safe from being modified by `Copy`
- It is self-documenting, if you are consistent in the use of `const`: pointer parameters that are marked `const` are obviously input-only, while pointer parameters that are not marked `const` are probably used for output.

**See also**

- [Output Parameters (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters)
- [M. Reddy, API Design for C++, Morgan Kaufmann, 2011. ISBN 978-0123850034.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123850037)

Comment: So what you are saying is that in the second example (the one with pointer) in my question, `dest` is marked as output only if the calling function reads the value and if it does not then it is an input argument? Thats very context sensitive and it may well be impossible to document such a function correctly. What if its called from multiple places and some only care about the return value (or only about the time the call takes)?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I added a 'Furthermore' section to my answer to address this aspect. I also added a section about using const for input pointer parameters.